# split columns by a delimiter in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a large table key(keyid,data) . In this table data consists of a text separated by /.
Eg x/y/z . I wish to extract the 2nd field (in the example y) for all the values stored in datails column in the table.

I tried using these

```
dblp1=# select regexp_split_to_array((select key from keytable),'/') as key_split;
```

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

```
dblp1=# SELECT split_part((select key from keytable), '/', 2);
```

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Both work on single string .

Answer (score 4):

Pretty close.  You need the function to be wrapped right around the column name, like so:

```
select split_part(key, '/', 2) from keytable;
```